# Data Massaging to Obtain the required data

Tags: r

My data file contains costs month-wise. These costs pertain to some cost buckets. I was trying to filter on some costs in that column (multiple entries for one cost bucket) and sum those costs month-wise for that cost bucket. Then I have to sum those costs into another cost bucket.

e.g. Multiple entries for SWB, Training etc. Need to sum up these multiple values month-wise and then sum them upto into another cost bucket - Personnel for example - say.

Following is the code:

```
list <- c("SWB", "Travel", "Training", "Relocation", "Contract Labor")
> for(i in seq_along(list))
+ {
+ temp <- dump %>% select(Line.Item.L1, Jan:Aug) %>% filter(Line.Item.L1 == a[[i]])
+ temp %>% select(Jan:Aug) %>% colSums(na.rm=TRUE) -> a[[i]]
+ }
```

It gave an error:

> Error in list[[i]] <- temp %>% select(Jan:Aug) %>% colSums(na.rm = TRUE) :
>    more elements supplied than there are to replace

Then, I used:

```
 d <- data.frame(a=rep(1,10), b=rep(1,10), c=rep(1,10), d=rep(1,10), e=rep(1,10))
> for(i in seq_along(list))
+ {
+ j=1
+ d[j,] = c(a,b,c,d,e)
+ temp <- dump %>% select(Line.Item.L1, Jan:Dec) %>% filter(Line.Item.L1 == list[[i]])
+ temp %>% select(Jan:Dec) %>% colSums(na.rm=TRUE) -> d[j,]
+ j=j+1
+ }
```

This shows a:e are not defined.

Please help me write this code

Comment: Please include a sample of your data in your question - use `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use gather() from tidyr to collect your month columns into a single column called month, and then group by them to calculate your sums?

Your example of the new buckets is a bit hazy, but you could do something like this:

```
list %>%
   mutate(new_bucket = ifelse(Line.Item.L1 == bucket_value,'bucket1','bucket2') %>%
   gather(key = month, value = cost, Jan:Aug) %>%
   group_by(new_bucket,month) %>%
   summarize(total_costs = sum(cost)
```

Anyways, I would assign the new bucket first in a separate column (if needs be, do it in a for loop) and then calculate the rest very quickly.

Comment: I actually want the costs month wise. I want to analyse the trend and seasonality of various costs. What I am trying to do is this:

I have costs for different cost buckets like SWB, Travel, Training etc which I'm trying to club into another head called 'Personnel'. There are multiple entries for every cost bucket i.e. multiple entries for SWB alone. First I have to sum up all those costs month-wise then add them with costs of other buckets, which fill reflect under costs for Personnel month-wise.

Comment: Right, the easiest way to do that is exactly how I outlined. You need to gather() the separate monthly columns into a single month column then use that as a basis for summing costs by month. 

If I understand your original post correctly, your data set is organized into 9 columns: one line item cost ID column (string), and eight monthly cost columns (integers).

Is that correct?

If you have a key that contains the line item cost and the buckets (SWB, training, etc) then you can left_join it to the data frame after you have gathered the months. Then you use that in your group_by() call.

Comment: `list %>%
   gather(key = month, value = cost, Jan:Aug) %>%
   left_join(bucket_keys,by='line_item_id') %>%
   group_by(bucket_id,month) %>%
   summarize(total_costs = sum(cost) %>%
   ungroup()`

Something like this will give you monthly costs summed by bucket.